# Google Sheets - searching combinations of cells for value maxes

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do some organizing for my characters in a video game I play. I'm not sure if/how I can do what I'm trying to do. Essentially, I'd like the "Max Crew Skills" cell range in the bottom-right of the attached picture to automatically update based on what I enter in the "Crew Skills" range. Hopefully the image below makes it clear. I hand-input the data as it is now but I'm wondering if there's a way to get it to dynamically update.

If, say, I fill in row 4 with new information (Skill 1 = "Armormech" and Level = "300") I'd like that to be reflected in the "Max Crew Skills" range. I can think about how one might do this manually (stack columns A+G+H, A+I+J, A+K+L together; sort by skill name and skill number; keep the combination with the highest number; print the skill/number/character name) but if I can get away with just some filters in columns P/Q that would be preferable.

Thanks!

[image: Table]

Follow-up: I was able to accomplish this via a lot of manual manipulation on a second sheet. I'd still love to know if there's a cleaner solution! The sheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SXCtTyrD69nqHmGG6Bpc5n9iKyDENnHN1Foxl04YQnI/edit?usp=sharing), feel free to take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Please, see [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QeE3U9kIh7JOmvHtL52HFfdIXxIV6vTURfLOf8DZXxo/edit#gid=0)

***Column O*** contains following formula

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(
 QUERY(
  {$A$2:$A,$G$2:$H;
   $A$2:$A,$I$2:$J;
   $A$2:$A,$K$2:$L},
 "SELECT Col3, Col1 
  WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
  AND Col2 ='"&N2&"'
  ORDER BY Col3 Desc
  LIMIT 1",0)),"No Character")
```

where we first combine all data into table form and then using [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en#null) we return MAX level of skill and Character name based on Skill name in ***Column N***